# numpy loading file error

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to load *.npy* file created by *numpy*:

```
import numpy as np

F = np.load('file.npy')
```

And *numpy* raises this error:

> C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in load(file,
>   mmap_mode)
>
> ```
> 379         N = len(format.MAGIC_PREFIX)
> 380         magic = fid.read(N)
> ```
>
> --> 381         fid.seek(-N, 1)  # back-up
>
> ```
> 382         if magic.startswith(_ZIP_PREFIX):
> 383             # zip-file (assume .npz)
> ```
>
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Could anyone explain me what its mean? How can I recover my file?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a file object that does not support the `seek` method. Note that the `file` parameter of `numpy.load` [must support the `seek` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html). My guess is that you are perhaps operating on a file object that corresponds to another file object that has already been opened elsewhere and remains open:

```
>>> f = open('test.npy', 'wb')  # file remains open after this line
>>> np.load('test.npy')         # numpy now wants to use the same file
                                # but cannot apply `seek` to the file opened elsewhere

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#114>", line 1, in <module>
    np.load('test.npy')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 370, in load
    fid.seek(-N, 1) # back-up
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Note that I receive the same error as you did. If you have an open file object, you will want to close it before using `np.load` and before you use `np.save` to save your file object.